# How can this var be written, to set the headerHeight, based on the width of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this on GitHub and it works perfectly if I am setting the height based on a landscape view or setting the height based on a portrait view but it does not compensate for both views.

How can I compensate for both views?

```
var headerHeight = '270'; // if you have a sticky header, add its height or it will cover your content
$([document.documentElement, document.body]).animate({
    scrollTop: $('.elementor-tab-title[data-tab="' + current[1] + '"]').closest('.elementor-widget-wrap').offset().top - headerHeight
}, 200);
```

Let's just say, var headerHeight = '270' is for the landscape view.

I wish to add to the above var a second height for the portrait view. A height of 320

[The snippet tool post was too long so I made a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jgh6xuno/3/)

Comment: Can you provide `Run code snippet` functionality or some sort of fiddle?

Comment: I continue to receive an error attempting to run code snippet:

Error{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 1047,
  "colno": 9
}

Comment: I get: 
Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 44895.

Comment: @learnmorecode It sounds like you're trying to post a snippet with too much code. You need to provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jgh6xuno/1/

Comment: When I use less code it does not behave correctly...